# JavaScript object browser?

Tags: javascript

I was recently tasked to document a large JavaScript application I have been maintaining for some time. So I do have a good knowledge of the system.

But due the sheer size of the application, it will probably take a lot of time even with prior knowledge around the code and the source code itself in uncompressed form.

So I'm looking for tools that would help me explore classes and methods and their relationships in JavaScript and if possible, document them along the way, is there one available?

Something like object browser in VS would be nice, but any tools that help me get things done faster will do.

Thanks!

Comment: I posted a connection a long time ago, and these MS ppl closed it "as fixed"! take a look: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=357013

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/1843)'s [DOM tab](http://getfirebug.com/dom.html) lets you browse the contents of the global `window` object, and you can inspect a particular object by entering `inspect(whatever)` in the command line.

You won't be able to use it to detect relationships unless an instance of one object holds an instance of a related object, but it's a start.

You can also use the Options menu on the DOM tab to restrict what's shown to user-defined functions and properties, which should help reduce clutter.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com), they have an outline that can help you to determine what are the objects and somtetimes their relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Firebug + uneval(obj) is a simple trick that is often helpful.

Comment: uneval is interesting... but I already have the source code in mint form you see... only there's not a single line of comment :-(

Answer (score 1):

I see a lot of people talking about examining the DOM within Firebug. However,  from your question it looks like you want something like jsdoc? just add type and class information through comments and jsdoc generates documentation including class relationships. http://jsdoc.sourceforge.net/

Google has a fork of it with added functionality http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/

**UPDATE:** It's not a fork, it's a rewrite by the developer that wrote jsdoc originally as a perl script. It aims at being more adaptable so you can use whatever js inheritance/events/properties style you'd like. Another feature is that it lets you modify the templates used to generate the HTML in a much simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

We don't know if this JS application is designed to run in a Web browser...
If yes, as advised, Firebug (a Firefox extension) is excellent at debugging JS and exploring Dom.
On the IE side, you have some tools like [IEDocMon](http://www.cheztabor.com/IEDocMon/index.htm), [Web Accessibility Toolbar](http://www.visionaustralia.org.au/ais/toolbar/) (it does more than its name) or [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/) (unrelated to your question, but still a good tool to have).

Answer (score 0):

**Firebug** (Firefox) / **Dragonfly** (Opera) can help you with viewing objects in realtime

**Aptana** / **JS/UML**(Eclipse) can help with relationships of objects

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but let me answer it anyway.

1. Use an *IDE*.  Integrated Development Environments were made for jumping around rapidly among the code.  The key features you will exercise during exploration are viewing the file structure or outline, jumping to a declaration or usage, and searching the entire project for all instances of a string.  If you are using WebStorm, set up a custom scope for files except generated files and node.js to aid in searching.
2. Run 'npm la | less' which lists all your dependent modules with one line descriptions.   You may have never seen moment.js and never need to read the documentation, but taking the time to read a one line summary of it is worthwhile.  If you need more information on a tool than one line summary, search for the term on SlideShare.   Slides are faster than ReadTheDocs.
3. Document a little as you go.   I'm a fan of forcing people to use notebooks constantly rather than scratch paper.  Also, I find adding a one line comment to each JavaScript file is worthwhile.   You want to know what should be in each directory of your project.  I also recommend building a glossary of the exact meaning of domain terms in your system, e.g., what does "job" in your system.
4. Finally, you may need to just fire up the application in a debugger and start stepping through parts of it.   Most large projects have accreted worth from programmers of various skill levels and motivations.

You are aiming for a level of "conceptual integrity" (to quote Yourdon) or to "grok" the software (to quote Heinlien).   It does take some time, cannot be bypassed, and can be done efficiently.